# what is an "associate orchestra"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I get stuck with this word combination and can't understand the meaning of the word associate in this context:

> The BBC SO is the **associate orchestra** of the Barbican Centre in London, where it gives an annual season of concerts.

Answer (score 2):

It is a specific *term* rather than a phrase, so don't feel too bad for not understanding it. That said, it is pretty self-explanatory.

For clarity, the "BBC SO" is the British Broadcasting Corporation's Symphony Orchestra.

An "associate orchestra" is simply an orchestra *associated* (or "*affiliated*") with a particular venue or organisation. In this case the venue is the Barbican Centre.